# rake dependencies vs requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have a rake task db:test:prepare that is meant to clear out the test db before tests are run. It seems that it is magically a dependency of the test, test:units, and test:functionals tasks which are defined as part of some core library.

When I run one of test:units, or test:functionals on its own, db:test:prepare runs first and the tests succeed. But if I run the default test task, the second suite of tests fails because the db wasn't reset in between.

Researching around, I find that rake dependencies will be skipped if they've already run once, so if I have `task :a => :pre` and `task :b => :pre`, if I define a third task to run both of those, `task :c => [:a, :b]`, when I call `rake c`, rake will invoke `:pre, :a, :b`, and not `:pre, :a, :pre, :c`

I ultimately got the behavior I wanted by writing a new task:

```
namespace :test do
  task :all do
     Rake::Task['test:units'].invoke
     Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].execute
     Rake::Task['test:functionals'].invoke
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or a way to declare that a dependency is *required* or somesuch? Rake::Task has a #reenable method, which I had hoped would allow a workaround, like to have the "prepare" task reenable itself at the end of execution so that it would be invoked again when the second task depending on it came around, but it doesn't seem to work that way.